# Using PyQt5 caused Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome Error

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt5, fedora, wayland

I am currently learning Python on Fedora. While I'm coding PyQt5 on Visual Studio Code, I got `Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.` error and couldnt find a way that works. So can you help me fix it?

Comment: Which application issues the warning?  Have you tried `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland that_command`?

Comment: I tried that command but it didnt work. But i figured the problem out. I accidentally delete some files i should not, after reinstall fedora problem had solved. VS Code issued the warning while compiling python btw. Thanks anyway :)